# How it happen. Identity Server4 User Login page redirection. Purpose of Redirect Urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I am quite new to Asp.net core identity and Identity Server 4. I am following online training course on implementing Authentication using Open Id Connect with asp.net core and Identity server 4.

If I further illustrate my solutions having Asp.net core mvc web application as **client**. Another asp.net core mvc web app as **IDP (Identity Server4)** and another asp.net core mvc web **api as resource server**.

For un-authenticated Users Login page on IDP is appearing. Problem for me is how does client web (asp.net core web app) knows user is not authenticated? My guess is when user first time access web app access token is not presenting on authorization header so authentication middleware knows this is not authentication request and redirect request to IDP Is it correct?

Then user redirect to Logic view of Account Controller how that redirection configured on IDP (I mean here is how exactly redirect to Account controller login page)?

Furthermore what is purpose of RedirectUris(https://localhost:44326/signin-oidc) configure on IDP. and how it works

By the way in here I am using Authorization Code flow and IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI AccountController comes from there.

Answer (score 3):

Either you know what api needs authentication, therefore, if you don't have this token available anywhere, you shall redirect the user to the oauth server. Once this one redirects back on your application, you will find the token in the url (a parameter of it if my memory is good). This token will have to be saved in memory for later usage or in your application db (standard browser feature). Then you can make a call to the api using this token that you stored.

If you don't know what api needs authentication or if your token is expired, you make the call to the api anyway, and then you get an 403 error (not authorized). Any 403 error should make the client application decide to redirect the user on the authentication portal to get an new token.

As you use code flow, I suppose you must develop a react, angular or any spa application. So I advice you to use oidc-client. It is a javascript library that is developed by the same guys who developed identity server. It makes the client very simple to develop when dealing with oauth authentication.

Here a more detailed description of the process and check/variable that are done/used:

- The client application (javascript/html5) makes a call to the resource server without any token in the authentication http request header
- The resource server (your api server) tries to get the token in the header
- doesn't exists. This means the request is not authenticated.
- The resource server return an 403 error to the client before even making any controller call or even authorization checks (roles and such)
- The client catches this 403 error, and then knows that a token is necessary for this call.
- The client stores the url of the request that failed and its post (if applicable) in the application db
- The client redirects the browser to the authentication server url, by transmitting the client id (the identifier of the javascript/html5 application for the authentication server), the scope (what set of resource that should be used by this client application in the context of this authentication request) and the url where the authentication server should reidrect the user back once he is authenticated.
- The authentication server asks the users to authenticate (in any way you can imagine, but most of time it is by asking him a login and a password)
- if the user is recognized by the authentication server (password that matches the login), this one will check if the return url (the url that was transmitted by the client application for it to be used to redirect the user on the right page once he is authenticated) is in the list of granted return urls for this client application (**the RedirectUris you are wondering about**). The point of this is to ensure that the the issued token is not transmited to an ungranted application (like a external javascript/html5 application hosted in china that could find a way to suck some data from your api server that only your user can know about and submitting it to a russian api server without the user even noticing it)
- it also checks if this client application (not the user... here it's to ensure that a specific client javascript/html5 application can access a set of resources) can use the scope that is requested.
- if checks are ok, the authentication server issues an access_token by signing it with its private key.
- the authentication server redirects the user on the initially transmitted return url, by setting the access_token in the url as a parameter.
- the client application get this parameter and stores it somewhere (anywhere you want, but most of time in the application db and in memory)
- the client application get the url that stored for the call to be done again, but with the access_token in the authentication header this time
- the api server (or resource server) receives the http request again
- finally find an access_token and checks if the it was actually issued by the authentication server (using its public key) since it is the only tiers that is trusted to issue a token.
- then it can trusts what is in the token: the user id that is mentionned inside, scopes (set of features) that are allowed to be accessed, etc...
- then it calls the controller and returns the response. If the token is expired, (a simple date that is in the token) it doesn't make any call to the controller and return a 403.

FYI, anything that is in the token can be trusted if its signature has been done by then authentication server. This system prevents the man in the middle security breach. Meaning: a guy who got a token by spying the network activity, changes what is inside this token so that he can make any call he want against your api server. Any changes that is made in this token will be detected because the signature (some sort of encrypted hash) won't match the new content anymore. And this signature, if everybody can check it in the world with the public key, only one tiers can issue it with its private key: the authentication server.

I tried to make it as complete as possible and yet still understandable for a newbie in oauth that you claim to be. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Stephane for detail descriptions. Buy the way I have one doubt on you note. when very first time user is accessing client application does it need to goes to resource server to identify it is not authenticated? I thought I would be identify by client application it self by authentication middleware. and redirect user to IDP?.

Comment: Still I can't find clear answer for how identity server redirect un-authorized request to Login method on AccountController on Identity Server QuickStart sample.

Comment: when the user access the client application (javascript/html), nothing should be asked for authentication. All the authentication work at client side is triggered by the application itself. Exactly like you would download an exe application on you computer, and that this application knows when and where asking to the user has to get a access_token. If you have this job done by a middleware, there is no proper way to have this token transmitted to the client application.

Comment: your accountcontroller is the one that is defined in the route that is called "authentication_route". This config is taken by identity server middleware when its url is the one that is called. Depending on the action that the identity server believes is required, it redirects on the right mvc page. Thanks to a service that was configured by identity server for dependency injection (IIdentityServerInteractionService ), you can transmit some authentication information during the execution of some actions and order the authentication system to make the following actions.

Comment: about the unauthorized  requests and how it is redirected, it works the way I described: the client detects the 403, stores the request somewhere where it will be recoverable later on, and takes the initiative to redirect the user on the authentication server. Can you give the precise example that puzzles you? And just to know, are you working on a single page application (angular, react or something like this)? That will help me to precisely explain what yon don't get in there.

Comment: Thanks for reply stephane. I found how it call account controller. It is all describe in here http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signin.html